# tengo diccionario y quiero extraer las claves pero con esta condicion

Tags: python

la idea es que tengo un diccionario {8:0, 4:0, 2:1, 1:1} donde  quiero capturar las llaves a partir de que el valor sea 1, en este caso tendria que quedar asi {2:1, 1,1}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Lectura recomendada: [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que has intentado aunque el código no funcione correctamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te he entendido bien, tu objetivo es, a partir de un diccionario, obtener una lista con únicamente las claves cuyo valor en el diccionario sea 1.

En ese caso, se puede hacer de muchas formas, pero una de las más intuitivas en mi opinión es list comprenhension:

```py
def f(diccionario, valor):
    return [k for (k, v) in diccionario.items() if k == valor]

dicc = {...}  # To diccionario
f(dicc, 1)
```

Como ha comentado HeytalePazguato, tu pregunta está un poco mal formulada, y es difícil de entender, si no era esto lo que pretendías preguntar, avísame y corrige la pregunta, y sin problemas intentamos buscarle solución a tu duda.

Comment: lo que intento es que me extraiga las llaves de los valores que tengan 1 y que solamemnte las llaves se almacenen en una lista

Comment: @ALEXANDERSANCHEZ, he modificado la respuesta, ¿ahora ya hace lo que tu quieres?